# Magento 2.0 Updating product quantity programmatically (Order data inserted using SQL)

Tags: magento2

What is the correct way of updating a products quantity?  I created programmatically an order by inserting data using SQL.  I would like to know how I can "update" the quantity of products added in my order.

Comment: Okay... step 1: "I created programmatically an order by inserting data using SQL." -don't do that. If you were using proper Magento techniques, like the order API, this wouldn't even be a problem.

Comment: Yeah I know, I am just stuck with some technicalities that's why I tried this manual approach first.  @RyanH. You happen to know if it is possible to set a "custom" payment method when using the API to create the order? or a possible workaround perhaps?  What I am actually doing is creating a plugin that imports orders from another non magento store in then saving them as Magento Orders.  This means that the payment is handled by the store where I imported the orders from.